# Android UI with text image within same rectangular block list

Tags: android, android-layout

I need a similar layout for my android application, but I am new to Android and have basic knowledge of android layouts.

https://lh4.ggpht.com/hlhm1gZbIFNXSHsgx6fB3BDU1sncvjrELOu7NVPpsaT5NiQ67c19LK1xCIOSf4oXey_K=h900

Can somebody share a similar code?

Comment: That is probably not just a layout. My guess would be it is a list view with a list adapter that handles the inner objects which have their own layouts. Looks like a relative layout picture left, text right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="@null" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/activity_cell" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/activity_creater_image"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/activity_creater_image" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/activity_creaters2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="dharmendra"
                android:textColor="@color/detail_text_orange_color"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/activity_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/activity_creaters2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="kumar"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/activity_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="kumar"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```